# Refresh all view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I working on messaging platform like whatsup.When ı send message ı must update the screen because ı am getting data in db.When i press send button ı must update View.
I googled but ı can not exact solution.Can anybody help me?

EDIT:

my code:

```
RelativeLayout layout=new RelativeLayout(this);
                LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                        1200,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                //layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);
                // Creating a new TextView
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(msgdesc[i]);
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                tv.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 0); 
                layout.addView(tv);
                bubbleLayout.addView(layout);
```

Comment: I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140050/6884103

Answer (score 10):

You will need to call either `requestLayout()` or `invalidate()` depend on what you update exactly in your view

If you just need the `View` to redraw so call `invalidate()`

If you change the `View` bounds (e.g. size) call `requestLayout()`

Answer (score 3):

if you use a listview with a listadapter, then you have to use `listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` this will update your listview with the new data

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with `view.invalidate()`?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

**Drawing**

> Drawing is handled by walking the tree and rendering each view that
>   intersects the invalid region. Because the tree is traversed in-order,
>   this means that parents will draw before (i.e., behind) their
>   children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree. If
>   you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw it
>   for you before calling back to its onDraw() method.
>
> Note that the framework will not draw views that are not in the
>   invalid region.
>
> To force a view to draw, call `invalidate()`.

you can try like the reply in this post invalidate the viewgroup:
[How to force an entire layout View refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991968/how-to-force-an-entire-layout-view-refresh)

Comment: note: If you are using a listView you can use notifysetDataChanged() to your adapter

Comment: I edit my code.Whic one is my view.I added my layout dynamically?

Comment: set the RelativeLayout layout; as a field in the class. And when you want to refresh it try with layout.invalidate();

Comment: ı add layout.invalidate under bubbleLayout.addView(layout);But it doesnt work:/

Comment: be sure that you assign RelativeLayout layout=new RelativeLayout(this); only one time (in onCreated)

Answer (score 1):

Finally if you have only a TextView in your layout try this:

```
//Supposing that msgdesc is a class field.

void myRefreshFunction(RelativeLayout l)
{
                if(l != null)
                {
                  l.removeAllViews();  
                  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                  tv.setText(msgdesc[i]);
                  layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                  tv.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 0); 
                  layout.addView(tv);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see [Dianne's answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/FL5dlnCMjQo):

invalidate() just causes the views to be redrawn: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

requestLayout() asks that the views go through a new measure/layout pass (and then redraw): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a messaging app and items are added to some kind of list, I suggest using a RecyclerView and Recyclerview Adapter to achieve what you're trying to do. When the list grows in size, your relative layout won't be scrollabe, a `RecyclerView` however would. On top of that `RecyclerView` gives you more performance with very long list because from the name `~Recycle~rView`, it recycles previous items and thus increases preformance.

Here's a reasonable tutorial on how to achieve what you want:
https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui

(I'm not affiliated with SendBird or anything, it's just the first result when you google: RecyclerView chat example)