# Calling super.onCreate() with null parameter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

In `onCreate(Bundle bdl){}`, we must call its super constructor by `super.onCreate(bdl)`.

For newly created activities, we got a null Bundle in `onCreate(Bundle bdl){}`. So when we call `super.onCreate(bdl)`, it is the same as calling `super.onCreate(null)`.

For reconstructed activities (like after rotate), we got a non-null Bundle. But I notice even if we call `super.onCreate(null)`, instead of `super.onCreate(bdl)`, it seems to be just the same. The layout restoration works are done in `super.onRestoreInstanceState(bdl)`.

So, is it really true that calling `super.onCreate(null)` is the same as calling `super.onCreate(bdl)` in all the cases?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is different...When your application pause for sometime, How can you restore it..? if you pass null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Android Source code, the `Activity.onCreate()` method forwards the saveInstanceState bundle to the activity's fragments. To be more specific, it fetches a parcelable with the "android:fragments" key and forwards this parcelable to the fragments using the `FragmentManager.restoreAllStates()` method, which itself restore the state on all fragments.

The `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState()` method forwards the bundle to the activity's window. Again it fetches the "android:viewHierarchyState" bundle from the saved instance and forwards it the the window using the `Window.restoreHierarchyState()` method.

So to answer your question, if your activity doesn't use Fragments, then indeed calling `super.onCreate(null)` won't change anything. But as best practice, I'll advise you to always forward the exact savedInstance bundle (unless you know what you're doing).

**Edit :** here are the sample source codes I talked about, taken from AOSP v17 :

[Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // [... some content ellipsed for readability purposes]

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable p = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
        mFragments.restoreAllState(p, mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null
                ? mLastNonConfigurationInstances.fragments : null);
    }
    mFragments.dispatchCreate();
    getApplication().dispatchActivityCreated(this, savedInstanceState);
    mCalled = true;
}


// [...]

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mWindow != null) {
        Bundle windowState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG);
        if (windowState != null) {
            mWindow.restoreHierarchyState(windowState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for answering! I will try about the Fragments soon, Could you please quote whereabouts in the Android docs talking about this? So I can read more in depth.

Comment: Well it's not in the documentation but in the source code. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again! If you could give us a brief example about what are the differences in Fragments would be very very very appreciated!!!

Comment: Sorry i need some times to digest and try about it. I surely will come back and tick your answer after i understand it. Lots of thanks!

Comment: Simply say, if we use `super.onCreate(null);`, we cannot restore our `Fragment`s. I have tested it in my code. I have another problem about `Fragment` and `saved state`. Could you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858854/where-fragment-save-its-state-when-fragmenttransaction-replace Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @XGouchet hi i'm got into a serious problem. think of a situation where i have hided and added fragments (2 or 3) with add to Back stack. Now if i'm at fragment 3 all the previous fragments are hidden and in back stack. i press home key. kill the process from ddmms. When i came back to application. The previous 2 hidden fragments are showing upon in the background of 3. Also pressing back key doesn't remembered the transition animation. Could you please help!

Comment: I know this is normal behaviour. Everything is recreated but how can i handle fragments so they won't get visible.

Comment: @XGouchet What do you thin about this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142255/retrieve-an-activity-after-time-out-warning-notification

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to find this out is by using Log() utility.

Although, bare in mind that you can put stuff into the bundle with

```
Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
bdl.putString("file_absolute_path", f.getAbsolutePath());
cf.setArguments(bdl);
```

And retrieve them with `getArguments()`.

So in short - it depends on whether you're using bundle arguments in your app. If no, then it's probably the same.