# Where Fragment save its State when FragmentTransaction.Replace?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

*Backgroud: i have a menu on the left, and different scrollable contents on the right. i wanted to save the scrolled position. But i failed. Then ...*

I have set up a very simple project to test it.

In words, i have a menu on the left, and different contents all holding an `<EditText>` on the right. (of the same class though, they are of different instances)

In codes, *(very simple)*

**content.xml**

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Please save my text ..." />
```

**ContentFragment.java**

```
package ... import ...

public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        System.out.println("Why this is NOT called ?");
        Log.v("onSaveInstanceState()", "outState = " + outState);
    }
}
```

and the program generated **MenuFragment.java**

```
package ... import ...

public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"}));
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).click();
    }
}
```

Lastly, our **MainActivity.java**

```
package ... import ...

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.menu, new MenuFragment()).commit();
    }
    public void click() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new ContentFragment()  // everytime load a new instance
                ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        System.out.println("... and this is NOT called neither :-/");
        Log.v("onSaveInstanceState()", "outState = " + outState);
    }
}
```

To test it, please DO NOT rotate your device.

First, choose an item from the menu, then type something in the textbox. Then choose another item and type something again. Repeat for a few times. Then navigate back and ...

you will find your texts previously typed **ARE SAVED !!!**

It is not surprised that the texts are saved ...

But it *is* surprised the texts are saved ***with all the `onSaveInstanceState()` functions NOT called.***

When did Android save them while `replaced` by `FragmentTransaction`?

If i want to additionally save some data into each `Fragment` instance (like the scroll position), where should i put my codes?

Comment: In addition, i found that the `Bundle` in `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState()` is always `null` (even when screen rotates, or called `FragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState()`). This a weird to me. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: With the [source codes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app), it is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Edittext save their own instance. See Yalla T.'s answer.

[How to retain EditText data on orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420396/how-to-retain-edittext-data-on-orientation-change)