# how to update the list of applications in a launcher?

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher, app-launcher

I created a launcher to use my tablet with multiple profiles, it is configurable, I can choose the number of users of the tablet, each one will have its own space, with a list of application chosen by the administrator account from a list view which contains all the applications already installed. this list once selected it will be saved in internal storage space. and the existing menu bar will be changed by the addition of new user. and each will have a new profile configuration file internally, my problem is to update in real-time applications, now, the update is only  possible if I restart the application, what is the mechanism in android I can used for growing update my launcher without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question:
[How to force an entire layout View refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991968/how-to-force-an-entire-layout-view-refresh)

I also want to point out that you could use less komma's and make smaller sentences. That makes it clearer for the reader.