# Android: Not save state when activity goes to background

Tags: android, android-activity, mutation

**I want one activity to NOT save state when going to background** (for example a spinner or an editText forgetting their state and return to original state when the activity comes back to foreground). How can I achieve that? **Note that this needs to be a one-line deal because it is for Mutation Testing purposes.**

I already tried the ***android:saveEnabled="false"*** in the xml of the activity, ***the onCreate(SaveInstance:null)*** in the creation of the activity and messing with the override of ***onSavedInstance(outState)*** but none of that seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991968/how-to-force-an-entire-layout-view-refresh
Does this accomplish what you need?

Comment: Just tried to use the recreate() and invalidate() and I did not worked either...

Comment: I did outstate.clear() and in some activities it works